# data type of Listbox Index

Tags: list, ms-access, listbox, vba

When I search information about Listbox, I see that most people use Variant as data type for the index number of the list.
Example:

```
Dim varItm As Variant
If Me.myListBox.ItemData.Selected(varItm) = True
```

Is it better to use Variant or Integer as data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two things.  When you have a multi-selection ListBox, users will use the following code because `.SelectedItems` collection has to be variant:

```
Dim varItm as Variant
For Each varItm in myListBox.SelectedItems
    'Do Something
Next varItm
```

However, there is [further documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835338%28v=office.15%29.aspx) on `myListBox.Sected(x)` where `x` is supposed to be `Long` but really could be any number containing variable.  Variant allows for numbers to be stored, so it would work, but better to define `x` as explicitly containing a number (`Integer` or `Long`) [More on Integer vs. Long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717521/4241535).

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 0 to myListBox.ListCount - 1
    If myListBox.Selected(x) Then
        'Do Something
    End If
Next x
```