# vba If within if

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I want to create a function which give me what contribution an employee has to make to a pension plan in function of its salary (with given down and upper limit) and in function of its age (doesn't contribute before 25 and after 64).

With the following code, I try to achieve that. I may have spend too much time on front of my screen but i don't see the problem. The debugger runs fine but I keep getting a "#Value!" alert. It may be the If-statment within another If. If someone may see where the problem could be, it would be very helpful

```
Option Explicit
Constant M = 1175

Function coti_min_LPP(x As Integer, salaire_AVS As Double)

Dim salaire_coord As Double

'The basis for the calculation uses the salary in different layers
If salaire_AVS < 18 * M Then 
salaire_coord = 0
ElseIf salaire_AVS > 18 * M And salaire_AVS < 24 * M Then
salaire_coord = 3 * M
ElseIf salaire_AVS > 24 * M Then
salaire_coord = salaire_AVS - 21 * M
End If

'Under a certain limit, the contribution is a percentage of the basis 
'according to the age
If salaire_AVS < 72 * M Then
If x < 25 Then
coti_min_LPP = 0
ElseIf x > 24 And x < 35 Then
coti_min_LPP = salaire_coord * 0.07
ElseIf x > 34 And x < 45 Then
coti_min_LPP = salaire_coord * 0.1
ElseIf x > 44 And x < 55 Then
coti_min_LPP = salaire_coord * 0.15
ElseIf x > 54 And x < 65 Then
coti_min_LPP = salaire_coord * 0.18
ElseIf x > 64 Then
coti_min_LPP = 0
End If

Else
'Above the limit, it is the percentage of a fixed amount
If x < 25 Then
coti_min_LPP = 0
ElseIf x > 24 And x < 35 Then
coti_min_LPP = 51 * M * 0.07
ElseIf x > 34 And x < 45 Then
coti_min_LPP = 51 * M * 0.1
ElseIf x > 44 And x < 55 Then
coti_min_LPP = 51 * M * 0.15
ElseIf x > 54 And x < 65 Then
coti_min_LPP = 51 * M * 0.19
ElseIf x > 64 Then
coti_min_LPP = 0
End If

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two immediate things that result in an issue:

- Instead of `Constant M = 1175` you should use `Private Const M As Long = 1175`. Why Long? Please look at the line `If salaire_AVS < 72 * M Then` if you add watch and go through your code in the debbuger you will find out that, if M is declared as an integer, after this line (according to watch window) M has value "out of context". This is basically due to the fact that you have achieved integer overflow. Please consider following code:

Example 1:

```
Sub test2()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Double

a = 1175
b = 15 

Debug.Print b < 72 * a

End Sub
```

- Option Explicit is a good practice, however requires you to declare all of the variables in your code. Declare them. You may remove Option Explicit for testing purposes. Some lecture on variable declaration: http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html

After above changes your function works for me (tested `=coti_min_LPP(27,19*1175)`)

Hope that helps. Btw. Please notice that having so many nested ifs with hardcoded values is troublesome to maintain, control and usually is not considered as good coding practice.

Comment: And consider long over integer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still doesn't work for my change the Constant to Const and deleting the Option Explicit.

I've learnt in college that Option Explicit was always the best practice choice, not really understanding why.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for your input. So you would, for any "numeric" variables, always use Long ? Does it have sth to do with computation time ?

Comment: I write     =coti_min_LPP(27; 19*1175) (Using the "Swiss" way of entering variables, if it may be the source of the problem)

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please try to change your const declaration.

Comment: It is I believe more efficient and avoid the risk of overflow.  https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/vba-code-optimization-why-using-long-instead-of-integer.3606971/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717148/integer-vs-long-confusion

Comment: This explains better than I can  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520

Comment: @QHarr +1 - edited my answer changing Double to Long :)

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle It is very very helpful. Thanks for your help and time. I feel a bit more VBA-able than before ! :)

Comment: Glad that it works for you. Please remember to mark answer as accepted if it solves your problem.