# How do you find the last row number in column VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the last row number in a column in a specific VBA Excel sheet. The row number needs to be put into a var for later use. Thanks in advance!

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim subj As String

subj = TextBox1.Text
lRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A").Rows.Lastrow

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(lRow, 1) = subj

For i = 1 To 1000

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(1, i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(subj).Cells(1, 1) Then

    End If

Next i
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be covered in an answer here in as a good a detail as it should, unless as a community wiki, IMHO. Please see the following as an example of why it all depends on your data: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm     That said, what should be mentioned is do not use Integer with last row as you risk overflow. Use Long.

Comment: `Integers` are stored as `Long` anyway, but they still have limits. So use `Long` all along.

Comment: And for more info......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717148/integer-vs-long-confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try elaborate already given answer.

To find last row/column, there's `End` method of a `Range` object. I.e. if you have `Cells(row, column)`, you then can append to it `.End()` which can have four arguments: `xlUp, xlDown, xlToLeft, xlToRight`. This function returns a cell (so `Range` object), so to have row/column number, you need to acces `Row` / `Column` property. To sum up, you should use:

```
Cells(row, column).End(X).Row
Cells(row, column).End(X).Column
```

where `row`, `column` are integers and `X` is one of mentioned parameters.

To find last row, you should use specific column number (for column that you want to know last row). You have two options there:

1. `xlDown` - you can think of it like this: start in a given cell, then go down until first blank cell is met. Return last non-empty cell.
2. `xlUp` - start in given cell, then go all the way up until non-blank cell is met.

**Note:** if you start with empty cell, `End` method will return first non-empty cell. On the other hand, if you start with non-empty cell, the `End` method will go until first empty cell is met and return last non-empty cell.

It all sound complicated, but let me give some examples:

let's have a sheet:

```
  A
1 1
2 2
3
4 4
5 5
```

then

```
MsgBox Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row 'returns 2
MsgBox Cells(5, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'returns 4
'start with cell in last row
MsgBox Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'returns 5
```

Comment: The problem with End() method - it doesn't work if some rows are filtered.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no data gaps then

```
lRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").end(xldown).row
```

Else if there are gaps and you want the absolute last then

```
lRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1048576").end(xlup).row
```