# Correct declaration of DWord in VBA

Tags: vba, winapi, integer, long-integer

I'm using an API function which returns a `DWORD`

Because I want intellisense on the `LoWord` and `HiWord`, rather than using a `Long`:

```
Declare Sub myAPI(ByRef outVariable As Long)
```

...as suggested in [this list](https://codingdomain.com/visualbasic/win32api/datatypes/) of WinAPI -> VBA datatype conversions, I'm using a type:

```
Public Type DWORD 'same size as Long, but intellisense on members is nice
    '@Ignore IntegerDataType
    LoWord As Integer
    '@Ignore IntegerDataType
    HiWord As Integer
End Type

Declare Sub myAPI(ByRef outVariable As DWORD)
```

However RubberDuck's [IntegerDataType](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/IntegerDataType) inspection reminded me that on 32 bit systems [VBA converts 2-byte `Integer`s to 4-byte `Long`s internally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/6609896), so I'm wondering whether my DWORD declaration is really 4 consecutive bytes as expected, or 8.

I'm not familiar enough with pointers and bits & bytes to picture in my head what's going on, but I imagine the API somehow knows to fill only the lower half of each part, as I've been getting the results I expect (I think) from the API.

Comment: More recent discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717148/integer-vs-long-confusion

Comment: According to GSerg in the link above the whole "Integer is stored as Long" thing may actually be wrong, even though it is written in the MS Docs that is referenced in your SO-Link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa164506(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

Your user defined type is 4 bytes is size, because `Integer` is 2 bytes in size.

You can check this for yourself:

```
Dim dw as DWORD
Dim size as Integer
size = LenB(dw)
```