# VBA Progress update in Status bar stops updating at exactly row 327 every time

Tags: excel, vba, progress-bar, refresh

I've created for loops in vba which update progress in status bar by the value of loop integer.
There are 2 loops; progress in one loop works perfectly fine **while in other it gets stuck though both are almost replicas**. Tried different files, rebooting, closing excel etc, every time it **stucks at row 327.** idk why, row 327 is not special, in different files too **it's always row 327.** **It's also not working so fast that it could be left behind.** loop goes through thousands of rows and with time gets pretty slow, so it moves like **one row in one second**; that shouldn't be too fast to update status bar simultaneously. **More Strange behavior is** that when it goes to next workbook after completing one file, **first loop still updates the progress bar again**, but second loop again gets stuck at row 327.

*I couldn't attach full code here, it's more than 800 lines, even this module is 320 lines so I attached a sample here.*

*(overall code works perfect, it's only the progress bar which gets stuck)*

```
for i = 2 to lastrow
Application.StatusBar = Round((i * 100) / lastrow, 0) & "% row " & i & " of " & lastrow

    if i mod 2 = 0 then
       'my code here
    else
       'my code here
    end if
next 

for x = 2 to lastrow
Application.StatusBar = Round((x * 100) / lastrow, 0) & "% row " & x & " of " & lastrow

    if x mod 2 = 0 then
       'my code here
    else
       'my code here
    end if
next
```

Comment: What happens if you move the status bar to inside the IF statement? (BTW updating the statusbar is an expensive method)

Comment: Does your code complete correctly if you comment out the calls to Application.StatusBar.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams what do think would be an efficient way of doing this if status bar is an expensive method? BTW my problem was solved by Fun Thomas, I was just curious if there's a better way in your mind.

Comment: @Cian - Usually I just update the status bar less frequently, maybe every 10th?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly assume that you are a victim of a numerical overflow. 327 * 100 = 32700, that value fits into a 16-bit integer. 328 * 100 = 32800 and doesn't fit into an integer. In my tests, I got an overflow runtime error with your calculation formula.

What I therefore assume is that

- You declared `i` and `x` as `Integer`. Best idea is to forget about that in VBA that data type exists, use `Long` instead, see [Integer Vs Long Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717148/integer-vs-long-confusion)
- You somewhere have an error handling routine that hides the overflow error that should pop up.

Declaring your variables as Long should do the trick:

```
Option Explicit

Const lastrow = 500
Sub test1()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To lastrow
        ' Throws runtime error when x >= 328
        Application.StatusBar = Round((x * 100) / lastrow, 0) & "% row " & x & " of " & lastrow
    Next
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To lastrow
        ' No runtime error
        Application.StatusBar = Round((x * 100) / lastrow, 0) & "% row " & x & " of " & lastrow
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG you're a genius, I can't believe it. You're right about both integer as well as error handling. Thanks a lot. Brilliant... Superb... out of words ...