# How do I write a macro which will create a "Publishable" version of a workbook (formulas removed) and save it to a specified SharePoint location?

Tags: excel, vba, publish

Unable to write a macro to automatically create a 'Publishable" version of an excel workbook (so that other people have access but cannot overwrite any formulas or see the lookup worksheets).

I need to create publishable versions of 6 workbooks each month.

All workbooks are saved in a Sharepoint Library, using the same naming convention ("2023 Training Matrix NOps", "2023 Training Matrxi SOps" etc.)

The publishable versions need to be saved in a sub folder in the Sharepoint library.

The code below, is the closest I could find to fit my needs:

#### Actual Outcome

- Creates a copy of the workbook with values and formatting only.
- Saves file to the same location as the original file.
- Removes formulas from the original workbook.
- Take a long time to run.

#### Desired Outcome

1. Save a copy of the original workbook (called "2023 Training Matrix NOps") to a sub folder within the original SharePoint folder
2. Name the copy "2023 Training Matrix NOps - Save Date" (e.g., "2023 Training Matrix NOps - 20_06_2023")
3. The copy of the workbook should be:

- macro free (file type xlsx);
- have all formulas converted to values;
- retain all formatting;
- remove the lookup worksheets which are all coloured yellow (worksheet names are "ADMIN", SF_Item_Extract_SF_Item_Status_EC_Report).

**It is critical that the original workbook is persevered in its original location, with all formulas and worksheets intact.**

```
Sub mcrSet_All_Values_and_Save_XLSX()

    Dim w As Long
    For w = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(w).UsedRange = Sheets(w).UsedRange.Value
    Next w

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs _
      ThisWorkbook.Path & Chr(92) & _
      Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Name, Chr(46)) - 1) & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy"), _
      xlOpenXMLWorkbook

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Workbook.SaveAs`?

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the conversion/rewriting of ALL the cell contents takes more time than looping through the cells containing a formula in .UsedRange. I haven't done any performance testing but expect this to be quicker

```
Sub test()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, r As Integer, c As Integer
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        With sht.UsedRange
            For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    If WorksheetFunction.IsFormula(.Cells(r, c)) Then
                       .Cells(r, c).Value = .Cells(r, c).Value
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

To remove the yellow marked tabs, add this at the beginning of the loop:

```
    Dim bDisplayAlertsBefore As Boolean
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If sht.Tab.Color = vbYellow Then
           bDisplayAlertsBefore = Application.DisplayAlerts
           Application.DisplayAlerts = False
           sht.Delete
           Application.DisplayAlerts = bDisplayAlertsBefore
        Else
           With ...
```

Because you are modifying cells and removing reference data in the same loop, you might want to switch off calculation during the procedure. Put this at the beginning:

```
    Dim iCalculationBefore As Integer
    iCalculationBefore = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

and at the end:

```
    Application.Calculation = iCalculationBefore
```

Comment: `bCalculationBefore` should be a long as `Application.Calculation` can be -4105 (Automatic), -4135 (Manual) or 2 (Semi Automatic).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcalculation

Comment: You're right, instead of a Boolean, we should use "Dim iCalculationBefore As Integer". I've changed it.

Comment: I'd prefer long.  [Integer Vs Long Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717148/integer-vs-long-confusion)

Comment: Thank you for the link. When we want a range check, integer would be better. I am not sure yet whether an integer is stored as a long or just aligned in a 32bit space leaving 16 bits unused. This needs some more investigating.